# Matlab limits on matrix size on 64-bit machine

Tags: matlab

I get out of memory error on my 32-bit machine for the code:

```
ones(10800,10800);
```

I don't have access to 64-bit machines, it would be interesting if you
guys test the biggest 2D matrix you can create on your machine
and report here.

Thanks, looking forward for a great thread.

Comment: basically as much as your RAM allows :) (probably your OS has an upper limit though)

Answer (score 2):

This is documented on the Mathworks site: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-IHYHFZ/index.html